# Best practice: how to make a CI pipeline fail if there are deprecation warnings in Ansible playbooks?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Recent Ansible versions do not treat deprecation warnings as errors, so there is no obvious way to make a CI pipeline fail if there are deprecation warnings. One solution I can think of is to collect output from `ansible-playbook --check` to a file and analyze it using `grep`, but maybe there are better approaches. A `grep`-based solution should work but it will not provide enough information on the context of a failure like line numbers, etc. What other possible approaches do you propose?

Comment: I think ansible-lint does this the best in terms of diagnostics.

Comment: @MattSchuchard Unfortunately, ansible-lint is not aware of ansible deprecations, it checks other things.

Comment: you are probably aware of this, it does not help in general, but in case of a play you could write it accordingly using [failed_when](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#controlling-what-defines-failure).